# RVM wants me to edit PATH in .bash_profile - I fear it is a mess

Tags: macos, bash, ruby, rvm

I am trying to get an Omega sub-theme running on my local machine (OSX 10.10) with Acquia Desktop Dev. Trying to run isolated ruby in sub-theme directory. When I use `rvm list` I get:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/khrysztov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.5'.

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I am not sure of the state of my .bash_profile. It looks like this:

```
PATH=“/Users/khrysztov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/Applications/Dev\ Desktop/drush:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.5.18/bin:/Applications/MobileDeveloper/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/MobileDeveloper/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools:/usr/local/bin:”


    export PATH
    export "DRUSH_PHP=/Applications/Dev Desktop/php5_5/bin/php"

    export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
    export CLICOLOR=1
    export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
    alias ls='ls -GFh'

    source ~/.profile

    [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Bash window is starting like this:

```
-bash: /Users/khrysztov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0: is a directory
khrysztov@khrysztovs-iMac:~$ /var/folders/bx/936smxc92dg_3pnf0zswj_f40000gn/T/DevDesktopConsole
```

When I look in Finder at /Users/khrysztov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin there is an alias (called 'ruby-2.1.5@global' that links to /Users/khrysztov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0 and that has a few gems in there. I did have RVM working before previously but as I was setting up drush it stopped working and I reinstalled and I am worried I may have conflicting files or PATH entries?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want that particular warning to disappear just add the following line to your .bashrc or .bash_profile.

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin"
```

Now just source the bashrc/bash_profile and the message will not appear again.